# ipython: temporarily go to shell and later return to current ipython session

Tags: python, windows, ipython

I'm running ipython from Windows command line. I wonder if there's a feature in ipython that allows me to temporarily goes to the shell (cmd.exe) and later returns to the current ipython session.

I'm aware of using "!" to execute shell commands. But that's not what I want.

Folks suggested a solution that work so I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14065704/695964).

Comment: You mean apart from using `!` to run shell commands?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, apart from that. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Never use Windows myself, but would `!cmd.exe` do anything useful?

Comment: Try `!start`, may be it'll work.

Comment: Since you've figured out a solution, you can put it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, please post your solution as answer to this question so OP can accept and close this qn.

Comment: @Monir: Posted, let's see what happens :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks commented and suggested an approach that works - use !cmd or !powershell to start a new command session, and return by exiting that shell.

Example:

```
C:\>ipython
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:22:14) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:

In [1]: !cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>exit

In [2]:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start a new console shell by executing the command `!cmd` in iPython. When you exit that console you're returned to the iPython prompt.

This is analogous to the UNIX trick of using `!sh` or `!bash` to create a child shell.